# jQuery form validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Is there a possible way that someone could make a jQuery form validator that live feeds whether or not the form is valid to the user. For example when logging in, and using too many characters (to prevent overflowing my databases).

```
    <input type="text" title="Username" id="user" maxlength="25" />
    <input type="password" title="Password" id="pass" maxlength="25" />
```

Then some jQuery (The max text values will be set at 25 characters).

```
    $("#user").on("keyup", function (event) {
    const max_length = 25; // the max length of the #user form element
    var inputed_length = $(this).length, new_length = max_length - inputed_length;
    var msg = new_length + " characters remaining.";
    var node_to_be_appended = $("<td class='in'>" + msg + "</td>");

    if ($(".in").length === 0) {
        $(this).parent().append(node_to_be_appended);
    } else {
        $(".in").text(msg);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is not clear what your question is, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend AngularJS for such "live" validation.
There u can easily show error messages and they'll disappear if the input is valid for example.

See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms or better example http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/form-validation-the-angularjs-way

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using jQuery, you can consider [this well known plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

A basic exemple can be found [HERE](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)